# creating a simple vu meter

Tags: ios, iphone

I just want to have my subject talk into the phone and display the volume on the screen.

Any recommendations for an approach?

Thanks.

Comment: why is this considered off topic??

Comment: As it says, *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."* In the future, try to be more precise about your situation. Try to find the tool you're looking for and if you have trouble implementing it, ask a precise programming question.

Comment: Trying to run the Apple example SpeakHere and as soon as I tap the record button it crashes with this message: SpeakHere[3677:70b] Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch.  I don't know why this is happening.

Comment: You should open a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check [SFGaugeView](https://github.com/simpliflow/SFGaugeView) :

> **SFGaugeView**
>
> A custom UIView with a gauge control (tachometer like control).

This one "Detects swipe gesture and sets the needle/level appropriately.", but with a bit of work you will be able to disable that.

---

You could use [LARSBar](https://github.com/larsacus/LARSBar) :

> **LARSBar**
>
> A UISlider subclass mimicking the awesome EQ slider found on Twitter's #music app.

If you need more precise help, tell us what you tried, what is working and what isn't.

Do you need help to get the level input in the mic ? Help to draw the view ? Be more precise.

Comment: This great. thanks. Not sure why the procedure police are so agitated, but this is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Please see https://github.com/ChiefPilot/F3BarGauge

[image]

From their description:

This control is intended to replicate/simulate the level indicator on an audio mixing board. These indicators are usually segmented/stacked LEDs, with several colors to indicate thresholds. This control replicates that look, using Quartz drawing primitives, and auto-adjusts to horizontal or vertical orientation. Additionally, the colors, number of bars, peak hold, and other items are easily customized.

Comment: And for getting the microphone level, see `AVAudioRecorder` a sample: `    [self.audioRecorder updateMeters];
    float peak = [self.audioRecorder peakPowerForChannel:0];
    float currentLevel = [self.audioRecorder averagePowerForChannel:0];
    self.microphoneLevel = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:currentLevel/80+1];
`

Comment: Thanks. Where is the AVAudioRecoder sample located?

Comment: For the sample, see the aurioTouch project with free source code from Apple

Answer (score 0):

Apple also has some sample code that can be used to get you started: [avTouch](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/avTouch/Introduction/Intro.html)